# Missing drivers on my ThinkPad

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, wireless, windows-7

I have a ThinkPad T440s, and I have been using Ubuntu 12.04/14.04. Regardless of what version I use, I consistently have issues with

- Brightness control (has an easy fix)
- Bluetooth startup  (has an easy fix)
- Unstable wireless (have not found a solution)

I am getting desperate, as it is very annoying that my wireless connection suddenly disables and then enables 1-2 seconds after.

**Final attempt at a solution:** I try and install Windows 7 such that all drivers will work. Then I install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside this. Will this possibly make it work?

Comment: So what wireless do you have?  In terminal enter `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and paste the results

Answer (score 3):

> I try and install Windows 7 such that all drivers will work. Then I install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside this. Will this possibly make it work?

No. The 2 operating systems have no correlation.

Besides that:

You are taking your Windows experience to another operating system. That is never a good idea. Ubuntu does not work like Windows and the system we are built on (Linux) had a total different approach of what an operating system is.

We have *generic drivers* that either support your system or it does not. If it does not someone (you?) needs to report those issues as a BUG against the package(s) it related to. If someone did that in the past for all your 3 issues they are bound to be fixed in a future release of that package. If nobody has the maintainer of that package probably does not know there is a problem related to your system (he is bound to have another brand computer).

> Unstable wireless (have not found a solution)

You will need to be more specific to get this fixed. Please have a look around Ask Ubuntu for wireless related problems and how to identity what brand NIC you have.

Also have a look at your system and router log files. Unstable wireless does not have to be an operating system related problem. It can also be a problem with setttings in your router (maybe you get so many incomming connections the router decides you are being [DOS](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service)'d). I myself used to be able to kill my wireless playing Guild wars on my Ubuntu system. The system decided I was being hammered and my home router could not handle it. I updated the firmware of my router and only when I started using [DDWRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) I could fix it by getting access to options I did not have before that.

When you have gathered all information please open a new question dedicated to fixing your wireless.

In case you (or anyone) needs help gathering info have a look at this post on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224209&p=13024222#post13024222). That script will take care of gathering all information.